# What are the sets on which norm-closedness implies weakly closedness?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Let $C$ be a convex, and normed-closed subset of $X$. It is well-known that $C$ becomes weakly closed subset of $X$. I want to know is there any well-know class of non convex sets which has this property?

i.e., a class of sets in $X$, not necessary convex on which, norm-closed implies weakly-closed.

Comment: Totally bounded sets have this property.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov  Yeah..  but that's a trivial case , because in banach space closed totally bounded sets are compact.

Comment: The proof for the convex case is by the Hahn-Banach theorem.  For a new, substantially different, case: you will probably need a new, substantially different, proof.

Comment: Another trivial case: the union of finitely many closed convex sets.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar  What if set be norm-locally convex?